# Concerning the open() function... file does not exist

Tags: perl

I want to upload a file (picture) to a webserver.

Here is a snippet of my code, when a button is clicked to upload a file this code should be run.  It runs fine until the line `open ( UPLOADFILE, ">", "$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";` but then the server returns an error saying "no such file or directory"  I've set my permissions properly, `open()` just isn't creating a file I guess; any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I reverted back to this, when the debug line is uncommented i get the malformed header from script. Bad header=/srv/www/vhosts/nimml-dev.vbi.: mausdb.cgi

otherwise i get:No such file or directory at lib_view.pl line 1025.

```
################################################################
# upload photo if requested
if (defined(param('job')) && param('job') eq "Upload File") {
use File::Basename; #for use of fileparse()


$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 100000; #max size it 10MB

my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";
my $upload_dir = $global_var_href->{'URL_htdoc_basedir'} . "/jel_uploads";
my $filename = param("jel_photo");
my $query = new CGI;



if ( !$filename )
    {
    die "Photo too large to upload.";
    }

my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse( $filename, '\..*');
$filename = $mouse_id . '_' . $name . $extension;


$filename =~ tr/ /_/;
$filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;
if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ ) { $filename = $1; } else { die "Filename contains invalid characters"; }

my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("jel_photo");
#use Cwd; use Data::Dumper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper("$upload_dir/$filename")); print(getcwd(), "\n"); }
open ( OUTFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!"; binmode OUTFILE;
    while (<$upload_filehandle> ) {print OUTFILE; } close OUTFILE;

}
```

Comment: have you examined the variables in the open command to ensure that the variables are being passed as you believe they should be?

Comment: It's traditional to include `$!` in the `die ...` message when `open` fails, so that you know what the actual error is . . .

Comment: edited and changed see comment below. and @thepip3r yes, The print command is correctly printing the filename and directory.

Comment: Please provide the output of `use Cwd; use Data::Dumper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($upload_dir/$filename")); print(getcwd(), "\n"); }` and the full path to the file you wish to open.

Comment: Does the directory for your upload really exist and has the user which operates the CGI script the rights to write to the directory?

Comment: currently the permissions are 777 just for testing purposes and it still isn't working.  I currently receive
Error message:
malformed header from script. Bad header=<pre>No such file or directory: mausdb.cgi

Comment: (There's a missing `"`" around `$upload_dir/$filename` in my code.)

Comment: @hopup, Then fix that error first. It has nothing to do with the question you asked.

Comment: @ikegami The problem is sometimes i get that error, and sometimes i don't.  I didn't this time with your code inserted at the top of the snippet i receive 

Global symbol "$upload_dir" requires explicit package name at lib_view.pl line 998.
Global symbol "$filename" requires explicit package name at lib_view.pl line 998.
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at lib_view.pl line 1423.

Comment: @hopup, Slow down. Take a breath and think before talking. Now place the code at the right spot and try again.

Comment: Error message:
malformed header from script. Bad header=/srv/www/vhosts/nimml-dev.vbi.: mausdb.cgi

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8364/discussion-between-hopup-and-ikegami)

Answer (score 1):

Add the reason for the `open` failure to your message:

```
open (UPLOADFILE, ">", "$upload_dir/$filename") or die "Can't open '$upload_dir/$filename': $!\n";
```

Comment: "no such file or directory at lib_view.pl line 1026" when $! is used

Comment: And so what does `$upload_dir/$filename` evaluate to?  I always include both this AND the `errno` seen in `$!` in my messages for just this reason.

Comment: $upload_dir/$filename evaluates to the correct directory, however I edited a few things and now i'm getting a different server error,
Error message:
malformed header from script. Bad header=<pre>No such file or directory: mausdb.cgi 

So this is not what i expected...

I pasted my new code in the original question.  Thanks for your help, if ti would be easier would you like to start a chat @JRFerguson?

Comment: Just because the directory exists doesn't mean you have write privileges to it.